# Apply a callback to a list of items with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am trying to modify the items in a list based on whether or not they match a LINQ Where query.

I tried doing it this way:

```
class Collection<T> {

    public List<T> Items { get; private set; }

    public Collection<T> Modify(Func<T, bool> query, Func<T, T> callback) {
        Items = Items.Where(query).Select(callback).ToList();
        return this;
    }
}
```

But this removes items from the list if it doesn't match. I would like to just skip over the item, and leave it in the list. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Use two variables instead of one.  You have Items = Items.Where(.....) so you are loosing the original data.  Make the output variable a different name.

Comment: Then how do I apply that to the original items?

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it too.  You can't keep the old values and the new value in a single variable unless you add another property which is set when a match is found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could do this:

```
 Items= Items.Select(e=>query(e)?callback(e):e).ToList();
```